# Centrar el texto de un botón, que es una imagen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Sucede que el texto de los botones cuando se le hace hover, no queda centrado ni horizontal ni verticalmente, de hecho, queda más corrido a un lado y no se alinea a la imagen.

Para hacerme entender anexo una imagen de lo que me sucede:

[image: Lo que me sucede]

Éste es un código de ejemplo:

```css
/*SERVICIOS*/
.efecto a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.efecto a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.efecto a:hover {
  background: #021645;
}

.efecto a:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.efecto a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="efecto">
    <a href="hombres.html">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/people" alt="1" />
      <span class="texto-enlace">MUJERES</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás posicionando el texto de forma absoluta, pero lo estás poniendo al 50% desde arriba (`top: 50%`)  y al 15% desde la izquierda (`left: 15%`). (supongo que esos valores son aproximados para el texto y tamaño que tengas, pero no es algo recomendable porque si el texto o el formato cambian, se descoloca todo).

Si quieres que esté en el centro tanto vertical como horizontal, lo tendrás que poner al 50% tanto desde arriba como desde la izquierda. Y además tendrás que añadir una pequeña transformación para que se ajuste automáticamente dependiendo del ancho y alto del texto. Esto se puede conseguir con `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` haciendo algo así:

```
.efecto a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando con tu código:

```css
/*SERVICIOS*/
.efecto a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.efecto a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.efecto a:hover {
  background: #021645;
}

.efecto a:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.efecto a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="efecto">
    <a href="hombres.html">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/people" alt="1" />
      <span class="texto-enlace">MUJERES</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Hola! muchas, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado, gracias.